# Python dataframe in one column strings delimit by comma, and in another column if pass or fail

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How I can count if a country that is in more rows , has failed or passed,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3JYL.png)

Like is

```
ID unique   Countries                    Test
1           Spain, Netherlands               Fail
2           Italy                             Pass
3         France, Netherlands                Pass
4         Belgium, France, Bulgaria         Fail
5         Belgium, United Kingdom            Pass
6        Netherlands, France                 Pass
7        France, Netherlands, Belgiu        Pass
```

and the result should be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpLLm.png)

```
             Pass   Fail
Spain           0   1
Italy           1   0
France          3   1
Netherlands     3   1
Belgium         2   1
United Kingdom  1   0
```

Because Netherlands is in 4 rows , and has 3 passed and one failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and last call [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(Countries = df.Countries.str.split(', ')).explode('Countries')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['Countries'],df1['Test'])
```

Comment: does `explode()` only work with `lists`? I tried directly on the original `Countries` column and it didn't work.

Comment: @KarthikS - than need only `df1 = df.explode('Countries')`

Comment: I tried your answer, and i get typeError: Dataframe is not callable, i m using an excel file , i tried to do something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows , and then counting if the value of a country is passed or failed

Comment: @GeorgeDascalu - Can you edit question with your code, especially what failed?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you, it worked , the mistake that i made was to put pd as dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael Done. Thanks again.